# Update user password programmatically

Tags: security

I am working on forgot password functionality.
I use default sitecore user provider. How I can update user password programmatically?

Is it possible to change password by manipulation with object of Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User class?

Comment: Yes you can pass the Name property of the User object into the Membership.GetName(string) method. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can't get the old password, you should use the reset functionality:

```cs
var user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(@"domain\username");
var oldPassword = user.ResetPassword();
var newPassword = "Mynewstrongpassword1!";
user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
```

To change the password, you need to work with the Membership user. But as Dražen mentioned, you can get use the `Name` property of the `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User` object in the `GetUser` method.

Comment: what type of user?

Comment: updated code example..

Comment: thanks. 
can you please also provide answer to my second question?

Comment: done - although Dražen already did too

Answer (score 2):

There is a way in case you need to build User Management tools for an internal support team. Let's say an admin needs to reset a password for a Content Author you can take advantage of **Sitecore PowerShell Extensions**.

#### Set-UserPassword

```powershell
Set-UserPassword -Identity michael -NewPassword pass123 -OldPassword b
```