# Is there a way to add Sitecore admin into core database?

Tags: user-management

By mistake I have deleted the Admin user from Sitecore(9) User Manger panel and now unable to login with default user id and password i.e admin/b.

I have run the below query but no record found in core DB

```
SELECT UserId FROM [aspnet_Users] WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin'
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert a new user, `sitecore\Admin`. Then follow the instructions on this question to set the proper password.

- [Is there a way to reset Sitecore admin password from database level?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/280/is-there-a-way-to-reset-sitecore-admin-password-from-database-level)

For Sitecore 9, you need @Derek Dysart's answer.

SQL for inserting into the Membership database would look something like this:

```
declare @now datetime
set @now= GETDATE()
exec aspnet_Membership_CreateUser 'sitecore','sitecore\Admin','pass@word1', '','admin1@contoso.com','','',1,@now,@now,0,0,null
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258123/81631

I believe you will still need to update the password and salt as described in the referenced post.

Alternatively, these are the values in a default installation. From the `dbo.aspnet_Membership` table.

```
ApplicationId   UserId  Password    PasswordFormat  PasswordSalt    MobilePIN   Email   LoweredEmail    PasswordQuestion    PasswordAnswer  IsApproved  IsLockedOut CreateDate  LastLoginDate   LastPasswordChangedDate LastLockoutDate FailedPasswordAttemptCount  FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart    FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount    FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart  Comment
DD20E696-45B0-4074-B50E-F34B47F1E454    68FFFAA2-1FFE-4006-B661-A8B6B80C81DE    Tm9jY7uSHNQnx08P70kiVEBO2YM=    1   n4n5/iUJKDrabOzQyLOU8Q==    NULL            NULL    NULL    1   0   2017-12-19 15:40:30.000 2018-07-10 16:05:48.587 2017-12-19 15:40:30.000 1754-01-01 00:00:00.000 0   1754-01-01 00:00:00.000 0   1754-01-01 00:00:00.000 Sitecore Administrator
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Mark Cassidy , We need to add one more row in db table "[aspnet_Profile]"

Steps to create admin user via SQL queries in Sitecore 9:-

```
declare @now datetime
set @now= GETDATE()
exec aspnet_Membership_CreateUser 'sitecore','sitecore\Admin','pass@word1', '','admin1@contoso.com','','',1,@now,@now,0,0,null

UPDATE 
    [aspnet_Membership] 
SET 
    [Password]='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=', 
    [PasswordSalt]='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==', 
    [IsApproved] = '1', 
    [IsLockedOut] = '0'
WHERE 
    UserId IN (
        SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin'
    ) 


INSERT [dbo].[aspnet_Profile] ([UserId], [PropertyNames], [PropertyValuesString], [PropertyValuesBinary], [LastUpdatedDate])
 VALUES (Copy and Paste User ID from aspnet_Users DB table for sitecore\Admin,
  N'IsAdministrator:S:0:4:Portrait:S:4:27:FullName:S:31:13:ProfileItemId:S:44:38:SerializedData:B:0:3875:', 
  N'TruePeople/16x16/Astrologer.pngAdministrator{AE4C4969-5B7E-4B4E-9042-B2D8701CE214}', 
  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, CAST(0x0000A2F500D2B376 AS DateTime))
```

Ref Link :-

1. Follow First answer given by @Mark Cassidy for Sitecore 9, use insert query
2. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/6021/1338 , use update query
3. https://egeek.io/sitecore-reset-sitecore-admin-password/ , use insert query for aspnet_Profile