# Reset Admin password in Sitecore 10.2 using SQL in Azure CM instance

Tags: azure, paas, cms-only

I am working on the `Sitecore 10.2 version` and the solution is deployed on `Azure PAAS`, Now I trying to reset the admin password to log in on the `CM instance`.

I have gone through with the below question posted on Sitecore Stack Exchange to reset the admin password: [Is there a way to reset Sitecore admin password from database level?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/280/is-there-a-way-to-reset-sitecore-admin-password-from-database-level)

I have executed the below mentioned both the script in SQL Server:

```
  UPDATE 
      [aspnet_Membership] 
  SET 
      [Password]='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=', 
      [PasswordSalt]='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==', 
      [IsApproved] = '1', 
      [IsLockedOut] = '0'
  WHERE 
      UserId IN (
            SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE
    UserName = 'sitecore\Admin'
      )
```

and

```
UPDATE 
      [aspnet_Membership] 
  SET 
      [Password]='qd+mxBSFWqmKYb74HfFjOZg4aZ0=', 
      [PasswordSalt]='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==', 
      [IsApproved] = '1', 
      [IsLockedOut] = '0'
  WHERE 
      UserId IN (
            SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE
    UserName = 'sitecore\Admin'
      )
```

But still, I am not able to log in with password `b`.

Comment: I think Dan's answer is the one you were looking for -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17204/2056

Comment: What password encryption do you have enabled on Sitecore side? If SHA512, then definitely check my comment above

Comment: its SHA1. <membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">