# I have created a new user in my local instance of Sitecore 10, later I was unable to login with the user which I have created

Tags: login, user-profile, sitecore-login

Below is the error I am getting. I have provided the correct credentials.

I have used the below URL for creating a new user :

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/create-a-user.html

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We will need more information than this to help you. How did you create the user - in which domain and what roles?

Comment: I have used the mentioned Url for creating the User, in sitecore domain and I have given developer and designer roles for the user. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you check with User Manager if the user is not disabled or not locked out by too many failed login attempts? Can you change password for that user and try login then?

Comment: @sushma try loign with username as `sitecore\<yourusername>`

Comment: Is this containerized setup or standalone ? If you cant login even with admin user, please refer this to reset password https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/280/is-there-a-way-to-reset-sitecore-admin-password-from-database-level

Comment: @MarekMusielak the user is not disabled or locked, I have tried to login by changing the password.

Comment: @SumitBhatia thanks for the input but still I am unable to login

Comment: @VikrantPunwatkar It is not containerized setup, I was able to login as admin

Comment: Is it a problem with a single user? Have you tried any other user except from admin?

Comment: Its not with the single user. I have created multiple user and none of them is working expect admin

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, our Sitecore account may become locked out due to incorrect password attempts (`5 invalid attemps` by default). And owing to that, you are unable to log in, even if you remember the correct password again.

And this can happen with Sitecore admin or any user account.

With `SQLServer/SSMS`, you can try to locate and with SQL query following the steps below.

1. Log into the SQL server and select the Sitecore instance’s core database to run the query to `locate the user`.Check if the specific user is `LockedOut` as below. [image]
2. Run the update query to `Unlock` the user.

```
UPDATE aspnet_Membership
SET IsLockedOut = 0,
    FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')
```

3. To unlock other account just replace the specific `UserName value`.

Now you can log into Sitecore using the correct password.

Please try and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is really strange that no users are able to log in except of admin.

Might be that in your version of Sitecore message from Sitecore about "Invalid username or password" is just misleading.

I would try one of these two things:

1. give Administrator flag to the user [image]
2. give at least minimal role to access Sitecore which is "Sitecore Client Users" [image]